# Error while converting java project to maven project

Tags: selenium, maven, selenium-webdriver

I just installed eclipse for Learning selenium automation i have added java environment variable but after converting java to maven project its giving me some error as follows:

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your pom.xml + errors as **text** rather than as screenshot(s). On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For formatting instructions see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

The *`<maven-compiler-plugin>`* looks error-prone. You can update it as:

```
 <build>
  <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Additionally you need to indent the *`<dependency>`* properly as follows:

```
<dependencies>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.0</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```